# How do I debug this form in rails to create a new User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck on how to debug it.  The current behavior is, when a register, which is basically creating a new record of the model User, it should create the record.

It just comes back to the same user/new view without creating it.  I don't see anything interesting or useful in the console.

I'd like to use debugger, but as I've placed it, nothing is useful.

Here is where the problem could lie, in the controller and in the new view:

users_controller.rb

```
6   def new
  7     @user = User.new
  8   end
  9   
 10   def create
 11     @user = User.new(params[:user])
 12     debugger
 13     
 14     @user.save do |result|
 15       debugger  
 16       if result
 17         flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
 18         redirect_back_or_default account_url
 19       else
 20         render :action => :new
 21       end
 22       
 23     end
 24   end
```

Here is the view/new:

```
1 <h1>Register</h1>
  2   
  3 <% form_for @user, :url => new_user_path do |f| %>
  4   <%= f.error_messages %>
  5   <%= render :partial => "form", :object => f %>
  6   <%= f.submit "Register" %>
  7 <% end %>
```

**QUESTION:  What could be the possible areas of failure, and how could I best use debugger to figure it out?**

BTW: I use AuthLogic on Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: you do have ruby debug installed right?  did you start your server with debugging enabled? rails server --debugger

Comment: Forms should point to create or update, not new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form URL (`new_user_path`) points to the `new` action of `UsersController`, which is why your debugger doesn't even run (it doesn't go the `create` action).

If you're using `resources :users` on your routes, you can [omit the URL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification) and it should work.

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
```

The reason it works is that when it's a new user object, the URL generated will be `/users` with `POST` method, which is translated to the `create` action of `UsersController`. If the above doesn't work, this should definitely work.

```
<% form_for @user, :url => users_path do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation for any version of `save` that takes a block,  can you show me where this is defined?  Or change your controller logic to this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
    redirect_back_or_default account_url
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

And your view should be using `:url => users_path` not `new_user_path` assuming your route for the create action was made using Rails' RESTful resource format.

EDIT:  On second thought you can probably do away with the `:url => new_user_path` option entirely since you're using the `form_for @user` method of creating the form, Rails is smart enough to use the right path based on whether or not the @user object is a new object or not.